# how to make text and arrow on same line. Text center and arrow on far left/right side

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow {
  border: solid black;
 border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
display: inline-block;
padding: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<p>Down arrow: <i class="arrow down"></i></p>
```

so I want the text to be in the same line as the arrow. I want the text "down arrow" to be in the middle and arrow to be in the  far right side but I have no clue how to do that. Please help I'm really new to web development. I'm learning html css and started javascript. I tried margin: left 200px; but it pushes the text too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first, you have two class definitions for `.down` that have the same instructions, so get rid of one of them.

Next, you need to alter your layout to accomplish the alignment. There are a number of ways to do this: float, flexbox, absolute positioning.

Here's a low-tech way that uses two `div` elements with the second one set to be absolutely positioned with its right edge on the right of the parent container.

```css
.down {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.wrapper {position:absolute; width:100%;}

div.middle { text-align:center; }
div.right { position:absolute; text-align:right; top:0px; right:1em; font-size:2em; }
```

```html
<br><div class="wrapper">
  <div class="middle">Down arrow: </div>
  <div class="right"><i class="arrow down">&ShortRightArrow;</i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks sorry that was a typo (i just edit it I replace one of the .down with the arrow). Also I am now running into the problem where when I make my arrow bigger the text is no longer in the middle of it (check edit code above please) Thanks for your help

Comment: To be it feels a bit odd to use absolute positioning for something like this, feels more fragile but anyway. Likely you do want position relative for the wrapper though?

Comment: thanks is there a way to center it such that the text is at the middle of the arrow?

Comment: solution doesn't work with multiple arrows. They are at same position so I have to hardcode it

Comment: @dragonn Your question didn't indicate that there would be multiple arrows.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved with some small flexbox styling, like this:

```
<p clas="container">Down arrow: <i class="arrow down"></i></p>

.container {
    display: flex; // Make this a flexbox
    align-items: center; // Horizontally center each item inside
    justify-content: space-between; // Push items away from each other
}
.arrow {
    // Whatever way you set your icon content
 }
.down {
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Do refer to the Flexbox guides since it's a great tool to learn https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: he mentioned he needs the text to be in the middle, I assume he means centralized text. So space-between won't work in the scenario. For it to work, first he needs to wrap his text in a, let's say, <span> element, then set this <span> margin to auto. The rest remains the same.

Comment: Ah, well you can also solve it with Flexbox and setting justify-self on the .arrow class instead (the result is similar to margin: auto but a bit more declarative)